# Oracle application express APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I was trying ot build a web application using Oracle application expressOnce. I logged out from APEX and logged in again leter.  I couldn't located my incomplete application.  How can I find my application so I can  continue work on it?

Comment: Make a new file and save it. The path where it is saved will be your default location and I am sure you will find your file there. Else let me know so that I can give you the exact path.

Comment: I got it.  I was looking at another account. Thanks!